# desk booking system in MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am trying to build a desk booking system in MERN stack but I'm having problems with front end.

[image]

I want the end result like this. Is there any library for this kind of map and its functionality in reactjs for front end?

Comment: Recommendations for off-site resources like libraries are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.